# Tool or Notepad++ plugin remembering a set of Search & Replace

Tags: windows, gratis, text-editor

I often have to perform the same search & replace operations with regular expressions. Today I do that in Notepad++, which works very well, except for the following case:

Notepad++ remembers recent search terms and recent replace terms. However, it does not remember both together and does not remember the other settings like "regular expression", "case sensitive", "match whole word only".

I am looking for

- a Notepad++ plugin (preferred) or
- another tool
- supporting normal + Regex replace
- that remembers 30+ settings together (search term + replace term + case + ...)
- for Windows
- and is gratis (commercial use)

It must

- find forward / backward / both directions
- replace single occurrence / all occurences
- highlight single occurrence before replacing

(basically the same as Notepad++ today)

I don't necessarily need

- find and replace in all opened documents
- find and replace in selection
- find and replace in files
- transparency

Answer (score 2):

[SynWrite](http://uvviewsoft.com/synwrite/) (open source, Windows) has find/replace in files; it has presets feature. In presets almost all of dialog options saved. 30 presets allowed, seems.

Usual find/replace dialog don't have presets though.

[image: presets]

Comment: Basically this is what I'm looking for. However, I often work with temporary files like `New1 *` which are not saved on disk. Also, SynWrite cannot be installed in standard program files directory (minor issue).

Comment: @Thomas, for finding in temp files, usual Find/Rep dialog is ok; w/o presets but with more features in it.